# css loader with image in the middle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the next code for my loader, is the same at w3school.

css:

```
#loader {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
  border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

/* Add animation to "page content" */
.animate-bottom {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-name: animatebottom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: animatebottom;
  animation-duration: 1s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatebottom {
  from { bottom:-100px; opacity:0 }
  to { bottom:0px; opacity:1 }
}

@keyframes animatebottom {
  from{ bottom:-100px; opacity:0 }
  to{ bottom:0; opacity:1 }
}
```

But if i put an image, the image spin like the css animation, i want a image at the center of the loader.

I use background-image in another div not work.

This is my [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/pcgfo8mx/1/)

Comment: correct me if i m wrong. What you want is that the image should not spin and should be present at the center of the loader right.

Comment: @Manish Yes, i want that

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Border` property from the `#loader_upload2` and add `background` there.

[Your Working Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/pcgfo8mx/2/)

```
#loader_upload2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 190px;
  height: 190px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;

  border-radius: 50%;

  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;
background: url('https://crunchbase-production-res.cloudinary.com/image/upload/c_pad,h_140,w_140/v1401689124/y1awpmexi2tf9l7eqnyg.jpg');
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

/* Add animation to "page content" */
.animate-bottom {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-name: animatebottom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: animatebottom;
  animation-duration: 1s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatebottom {
  from { bottom:-100px; opacity:0 }
  to { bottom:0px; opacity:1 }
}

@keyframes animatebottom {
  from{ bottom:-100px; opacity:0 }
  to{ bottom:0; opacity:1 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div id="loader_upload2">

      </div>
      <div id="image">

      </div>
```

css

```
   #image{
background: url(https://crunchbase-production-res.cloudinary.com/image/upload/c_pad,h_140,w_140/v1401689124/y1awpmexi2tf9l7eqnyg.jpg) no-repeat;
    z-index: 99999;
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    width: 90px;
    height: 90px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    lefT: 50%;
    margin-left: -36px;

}
#loader_upload2 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 190px;
  height: 190px;
  margin: -75px 0 0 -75px;
  border: 16px solid #808080;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 16px solid #85C440;
  width: 140px;
  height: 140px;

  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

/* Add animation to "page content" */
.animate-bottom {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-animation-name: animatebottom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: animatebottom;
  animation-duration: 1s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatebottom {
  from { bottom:-100px; opacity:0 }
  to { bottom:0px; opacity:1 }
}

@keyframes animatebottom {
  from{ bottom:-100px; opacity:0 }
  to{ bottom:0; opacity:1 }
}
```

demo:https://fiddle.jshell.net/mhrjnsa1/pcgfo8mx/13/